# Shift through an unordered list and change the position of the list items inside

Tags: javascript, css, events

I am building a small app, that lets you go through people businesscards, 3d style.
Basically, I have an unordered list, containing 10 list items. Each time I press the down arrow on the left, I want to remove the first

(the one at the front) and push it at the back (so it becomes the last

in the list).

Also, since all of the items, except the first one, have negative transformZ values to push them back, I want to rearrange them so they come closer to the user, each time the down btn is pushed. Right now each of them has a 80*i for a transformZ value and I have no idea how to push them towards without messing up the same layout.

I tried doing something like, but unfortunately it doesn't do the trick:

```
btnDown.addEventListener('click', function() {
        listItems[0].parentNode.removeChild(listItems[0]);
        for (i=0; i<=listItems.length-1;i++) {
            list.style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(0deg) translateZ(-" + (100*i) + "px)";    
        }
```

}, false);

You can also find the complete project here:
http://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/cbdwl

Thanks in advance, all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
btnDown.addEventListener('click', function() {  
  listItems[0].parentNode.appendChild(listItems[0]);
  // re-index list
  listItems = document.querySelectorAll('#primary ul li')
  for (i=0; i<=listItems.length-1; i++) {
    listItems[i].style.webkitTransform = "rotateX(0deg) translateZ(-" + (80*i) + "px) translateY(-" + i*20 + "px)";
  }
}, false);
```

You were close. Instead of removing the item, move it to the end of the node. Then re-apply the webkitTransform.

```
btnUp.addEventListener('click', function() {  
 var lastItem = listItems[listItems.length-1]
  listItems[0].parentNode.insertBefore(lastItem, listItems[0]);
  listItems = document.querySelectorAll('#primary ul li');
  applyWebkitTransform();
}, false);
```

For the up button use the insertBefore() function. See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cAbKI

Comment: @Cobote: +1. Just a suggestion, you can make that for loop as one function and call it both on load and after button event instead of writing the same lines again :)

Comment: Just one additional question. What is the best way to reverse the effect then btnUp is hit?

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Two final questions:
Why do I have to declare listItems in the event listener again? I've already declared it globally and it should have acess to it?
And secondly, what is the best way to have the same effect, but on scrolling?